# Angularjs rz-slider not returning value on keyboard arrow keys

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-slider

Hi I am using latest version of AngularJS rz slider . I am able to fetch changed value from slider for mouse events. But I am not able to fetch the changed/final value on keyboard event keys like arrow keys although I see the slider moving

Below is my code
          html :

```
      <rzslider id="slider.options.id" name="slider.options.id"          
      class="custom-slider" rz-slider-model="slider.value" rz-slider- 
           options="slider.options"></rzslider>
```

controller :

```
      this.options = {
            id: id,
            ceil: 150,
            floor: 0,
            step: 0.1,
            precision: 1,
            translate: function (value) {
                return value + '%';
            },
            onEnd: function (id, newValue) {
            alert(newValue)
            //},
```

I am fetching value from onEnd event. Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: You don't need to use the onEnd event, just see if the `$scope.slider.value` is updated.

Comment: What if I want to do custom logic in onEnd event

Comment: You can use `$scope.slider.value` directly